# Elasticsearch Query that can list an UniqueID that misses data

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im new to elasticsearch and i really need some help to get a thing done.

Every user has it own unique ID, ex; 111112,111113,111114.
Every user is connected to a user type, Ex; AA, AB,AC,AD
And every user type has one or more colors, Ex; Blue, Red, Black.

What im trying to achieve is a list of those Uniqie IDs in User type AA that does not have the color red.

(List UniqueID=* UserType=AA Missing=Red)

Is this possible? I know some basic querys, but listing IDs that miss something was a bit hard me and my knowledge.

Its easy in SQL with "Except", but i cant find out how to do it in elasticsearch.

Comment: SELECT distinct UniqueID
  FROM [wDB].[dbo].[tblKibData]

  except

  SELECT distinct UniqueID
  FROM [wDB].[dbo].[tblKibData]
  where fName = 'red'

Comment: Look at bool query in Elasticsearch docs

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. The query dsl is actually not too difficult to understand if you play around a bit.

```
PUT tmp
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "uid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "colors": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST tmp/_doc/1
{
  "uid": "alpha",
  "type": "AA",
  "colors": [
    "red",
    "green"
  ]
}

POST tmp/_doc/2
{
  "uid": "bravo",
  "type": "AA",
  "colors": [
    "blue"  
  ]
}

GET tmp/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "AA"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "colors": "red"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Vincent. 
Actually all data is already there. What i wanted is the search query, that was not very clear in my question maybe. 

Your search query is a progress for me, i get a result:

{
  "took": 43,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 31,
    "successful": 31,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}


Is it possible to get a list of theese 31 total?

Comment: @D.Granér the 31 is the # of shards the search was executed on, its not a count of documents. Can you add the index mapping you're using into your post?